# Bijective function question

Tags: functions

[image]

I need help with proving f is onto.  Thanks.

Comment: $f(1,1) = f(1,0)$ so it is not one-to-one! If by $Z^+$ you mean zero is included .

Comment: How on earth did you prove it's one-to-one???

Comment: @nonlinearthought I'm fairly certain $\mathbb{Z}^+$ refers to the positive integers only, not including zero

Comment: I think that given $N$ one chooses the  largest $n$ such that $N$ is greater than $\binom{n}{2}$ is positive, and then using the difference as $i$ and the corresponding $j$ we have a solution.

Comment: Ok, I misread the formula (I had $-i$ instead of $+i$), so yes, it actually _is_ one-to-one

Answer (score 0):

Notice these two facts.

The following equality should be clear: $f(i,j)+1=(i+1,j-1)$.

Also we consider what happens when $j=1$. 
$f(i,1)+1=\frac{(1+i-1)(1+i-2)}{2}+i+1=\frac{i^2-i}{2}+i+1=\frac{i^2+i}{2}+1=\frac{(1+(i+1)-2)(1+(i+1)-1)}{2}=f(1,i+1)$

In other words, if $i_1+j_1<i_2+j_2$, then we know that $f(i_1,j_1)<f(i_2,j_2)$.
Otherwise, if $i_1+j_1=i_2+j_2$, then $f(i_1,j_1)<f(i_2,j_2)$ iff $i_1<i_2$. Formally, you can prove this using induction.

Now looking at $f(1,1)=1$ shows that it is onto.

Comment: Sorry lost me at "In other words..." Don't see how you obtain $ f(i_1,j_1)<f(i_2,j_2)$

Comment: Maybe it was not said in the most clear way but when $i_1+j_1=i_2+j_2$, $f(i_1,j_1)<f(i_2,j_2)$ iff $i_1<i_2$. This follows from $f(i,j)+1=f(i+1,j-1)$.